# Orchard - how to remove a field from a form (content type)

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have created a 'content type' which incorporates a 'content part', which allows the user to upload an image.

Iv then created a 'form' which uses this image loader 'content type' to display on screen, from the front end menu.

However when the user tries to upload an image from the front end a text box displaying owner appears at the bottom. I want to set this to invisible. does anyone know how to do this?

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `ContentTypes` from dashboard,select your `ContentType`  - click edit and then expand `CommonPart`  - uncheck the `Show editor for owner` check box as shown in the picture :

[image]